# Are cookies secure if they are never sent to a server

Tags: security, cookies

Is a cookie secure if it is only stored locally on the client's browser and never sent over the internet to a server?

Edit - Im making an encrypted file service, the way it works is that the user has two passwords, one for logging into his account and another for encrypting and decrypting their files. Upon logging in they are presented with a window that asks them for their decryption password. This password is stored in a cookie on the user's browser. A encrypted list of files is sent from the server and javascript uses the cookie to decrypt it(and encrypt uploaded files once in the browser and then php encrypts it on the server). Is this a secure way of doing things or is their a better way? P.S. I do use an SSL but I'm trying to add more security.

Comment: A) this probably should be on security.stackexchange B) secure against what?  and C) how do you propose setting them to ensure they never get sent to a server (depending on use case, localstorage might make more sense)

Comment: Can you edit your post to explain what you want to know in more detail. I suspect it is not so much the security of the cookie that you care about, so much as the security of the owner of the browser once the cookie is stored.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but how secure it is, it still depends on what information you stored in that cookie. For authentication, it's best to use session and server-side validation.